# Auto attach new consoles to conemu

Tags: console, conemu

I want that when a console is openning ConEmu will automagically detect the console (for example - by executable path) and attach it in a new tab.

for example, a console of an application I'm developing therefore anytime I start it in debug mode a console is open - I want the ConEmu to detect that and attach it.

Is this possibe?
How?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can help, especially if consoles are opened through `cmd.exe`:

[image]

Comment: This helps only when I run cmd.exe, but if I run another console app (i.e. TomEE server or a console app I developing via VisualStudio) This doesn't work, Is there something Im missing?

Comment: No! It helps when you run **any** console application from hooked executable. And surprisingly there is a field for configure them (hooked executables).

Comment: wow, the author. i'm honored :-) thank you for developing and sharing such a cool tool with tabbed/full screen features :-)

Comment: @Maximus thanks for your amazing software & comment. I think Im having other problem, when I try to auto hook TomEE server it just close the console window & not attaching anything. but when I do it manually - it works fine. can you please advice?

Comment: @yossico SU is not a right place for investigations. ProcessMonitor, ProcessExplorer, screenshots, ConEmu LogFiles and so on...

Comment: Image link is dead... What was this setting ?