# ConEmu - hooked process not auto attaching new console - DFHack console (Dwarf Fortress)

Tags: conemu

So I've found a great superuser question that deals with [auto attaching consoles to conemu](https://superuser.com/questions/844366/auto-attach-new-consoles-to-conemu) the problem is that the solution proposed doesn't seem to work for my situation.

I'm looking to have the dfhack console, which runs with dwarf fortress, auto attach to my running conemu instance.

The dfhack console is listed as having the same image name as the game's main window. They share a PID, have the same image path, and image name, every other column differs however.

I've tried listing `dfhack-run.exe`, `Dwarf Fortress.exe` and even the initial launcher `lnp.exe` not really sure there is much else I can try. Worth putting the question out there though. Seems to me this might be a problem with how ConEmu hooks processes and how the dfhack console starts after the main game window comes alive.

Comment: Nothing is clear... Do you already have a console process in ConEmu? What process creates *another* console? What is the process tree from [ProcessExplorer](http://conemu.github.io/en/ProcessExplorer.html).

Comment: So, what did you try to configure already?

Comment: @Maximus updated the question, but I think this likely would need to find its way to an issue tracker as a feature request or maybe as a bug